# Как создать MyComponent?

Tags: reactjs

как можно применить наследование в ReactJS ?

попробовал так, но получил ошибку при сборке:

view.jsx:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import {MyPage} from '../common/mypage';

class View extends MyPage {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChange = super.onChange.bind(this);

        self.state = {
            test: ''
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-wrapper">
                    <input type="text"
                           placeholder="Enter"
                           value={this.state.test}
                           onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                    ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        items: state.items
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        onAddItem: (item) => {
            dispatch(addItem(item));
        },
        onGetItems: (o) => {
            dispatch(getItems(o));
        }
    })
)(View);
```

mypage.jsx:

```
import {Component} from 'react';

export class MyPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }

    onChange(e) {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-wrapper">
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

> ERROR in ./app/test/View.jsx
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../common/mypage' in '/home/dev/project/app/test'
>
> @ ./app/test/View.jsx 37:12-37
>
> @ ./app/test/index.jsx

`UPDATE`

спасибо `Mikhail Chibel`

ошибка была в путях, поправил и получил новую ошибку:

> inherits.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

ругается на render во View, но не понимаю как исправить

`UPDATE2`
все заработало, ошибка в коде была

Comment: У Вас ошибка в импорте, проверьте путь. Он должен быть относительный к  текущему файлу

Comment: А вообще офицальная позиция разработчиков React это использовать композицию а не наследование.

Comment: @MikhailChibel, согласен, но некоторый функционал хочется разместить в предке, а не в других компонентах

Comment: @MikhailChibel оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ